# Como tocar um áudio em background?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo um programa python que roda dentro de um loop infinito..

Em determinadas condições preciso tocar um audio, porém não posso esperar o áudio terminar para continuar o processo.
Pensei em algo async, ou seja, enquanto estou rodando o processo (loop) uma thread é criada para tocar o audio enquanto todo resto continua. Bem isso estou falando pensando na minha linguagem de desenvolvimento (C#) em Python não sei como fazer

tentei com subprocess mas ele basicamente só abre um AVL da vida e toca ele, e mesmo assim não é um play não assistido

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if condicao1 > condicao2:
        PlayAudio ##toca o audio e continua
        #Gravalog()
```

Answer (score 2):

Toque o Audio como uma tarefa paralela usando Thread.

```
import threading

def audio():
    PlayAudio ##toca o audio e continua

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if condicao1 > condicao2:
        threading.Thread(target=audio).start() # Executa o Audio em uma Tarefa Paralela.
        #Gravalog()
```